# python split string every 3 lines

Tags: python

i need to split this string every 3 lines and add it to a list is it possible?

```
a_string = """
LINE 1
LINE 2
LINE 3
LINE 4
LINE 5
LINE 6"""

split_strings = []
n  = 3
for index in range(0, a_string.count('\n'), n):
    split_strings.append(f"{a_string[index : index + n]}")




n = 0
for s in split_strings:
    print(split_strings[n])
    print("----------------------------------------------------------")
    n = n+1
```

and I get this output:

```
LI
----------------------------------------------------------
NE
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `["\n".join(a_string.split("\n")[i:i + 3]) for i in range(1, a_string.count("\n"), 3)]`

Comment: @d.b ty it worked like a charm!

Comment: @klix the above answer is not efficient. It reads the string 
as many times as there is a split (plus one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex:

```
import re
re.findall('((?:[^\n]+\n?){1,3})', a_string)
```

Output:

```
['LINE 1\nLINE 2\nLINE 3\n', 'LINE 4\nLINE 5\nLINE 6']
```

If you want a list of lists:

```
import re
[x.strip().split('\n') for x in re.findall('((?:[^\n]+\n?){1,3})', a_string)]
```

Output:

```
[['LINE 1', 'LINE 2', 'LINE 3'],
 ['LINE 4', 'LINE 5', 'LINE 6']]
```